# Stick through? or something else?

Tags: idioms

When I am trying to say I'll hang on and persist through tough situations, I first thought of 'sticking through', but today when I think about it, I am not sure if this usage is correct so I found its definition https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stick+through, which isn't what I thought. Am I right about this usage?

Comment: That's interesting; I understood what you meant, but apparently you're right and that isn't the correct idiom for it. The same free dictionary says that would be "stick out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've confused *stick through* with the idiom you want, which is quite similar: [**stick it out**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stick-it-out).

> [Cambridge Dictionary]
>
> to continue to the end of a difficult or unpleasant situation:
> *I know things are difficult right now, but if we just stick it out, I'm sure everything will be OK in the end.*

Comment: And then maybe conflated with things like "pull through".